# Watershed extraction using different DEM tiles

Tags: qgis, dem, watershed

I would like to extract the watersheds for a particular area using QGIS.  However, I only have Aster 30m DEMs to work with, each tile covering one degree square.  The problem is that I need to use four different tiles and the results do not all correlate where they meet.  How can I resolve this, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to create a mosaic out of the rasters and doing one watershed computation?
This link is helpful for [raster mosaics](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-working-with-rasters-in-qgis.html) in qgis.  Trying to make separate basins and putting them together probably won't work due to edge contamination.

Comment: Thank you so much :)  This makes sense and I'll certainly give it a try and provide feedback.